# Fetching and deleting all slash commands in discord.js v13

Tags: discord.js

I followed [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ApplicationCommandManager?scrollTo=fetch) part in the discordjs docs to fetch all commands. But that way it only shows the commands count and doesnt tell me the id of the commands. How do I fetch all the commands and delete all of them? This is the code in that page. It didnt work yet so I dont have a delete code currently

```js
guild.commands.fetch()
  .then(commands => console.log(`Fetched ${commands.size} commands`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delete all your commands, you can do this:

```js
guild.commands.set([])
```

What that does is set your command list for that guild to an empty array, essentially "deleting" all of your commands for the guild.

Comment: Thanks! This works but what about global commands? Are they deleted but update after ~1h?  

Edit: nvm i followed the `set` section in the doc page and it worked

Comment: Same concept, but like `<Client>.application.commands.set([])` instead